# AWS Redshift overloading procedure name doesn't work

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, overloading

I am investigating how procedure name overloading works in AWS Redshift and keep encountering an issue. Below is a test script:

```
create or replace procedure sp_test_1(in_int integer)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    raise notice '1 %', in_int;
end
$$
;
create or replace procedure sp_test_1(in_int integer, in_text varchar)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    raise notice '2 % %', in_int, in_text;
    call sp_test_1(in_int);
end
$$
;
call sp_test_1(1)
;
call sp_test_1(12, '2'::varchar)
;
```

Error messages:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: sp_test_1(integer) is a procedure
Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.;

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: sp_test_1(integer, character varying) is a procedure
Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.;
```

How shoud I modify procedure signatures to make procedure name overloading work?

UPD: `version()` returns the following

PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.24066

Answer (score 0):

In amazon-redshift, there have no option to check if procedure exist before DROP procedure [Check Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DROP_PROCEDURE.html).

And in your code, you are creating or replace your procedure . Thus you don't need to drop your procedure before write **CREATE OR REPLACE** procedure.

Please remove below 2 line from your code.

1. drop procedure sp_test_1(integer);
2. drop procedure sp_test_1(integer, varchar);

Then your procedure will run without error.

Comment: `drop procedure` statements were redundant, so I dropped them. But it's not the issue I try to sort out.